# regular expression or wild card in tasklist

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to use regular expression or wild card in tasklist

I have imagename going to be different for every build like AB1adf.exe, AB2dfas.exe, AG3dfas.exe ect

I have tried below but did not work..

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq AB%.exe" | find /i "AB%.exe" 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq AB*.exe" | find /i "AB*.exe"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension breaks the wild card:

```
C:\>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chr*.exe"
ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.
```

Lose it:

```
C:\>tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chr*"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
chrome.exe                    4376 Console                    1    313,076 K
chrome.exe                    4384 Console                    1      4,328 K
chrome.exe                    4548 Console                    1     94,260 K
```

Answer (score 0):

find does not support wild cards. You have two options `wmic` and findstr:

```
tasklist | findstr /i /r "ab.*exe"
```

or with wmic and [wql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) (which allows richer expressions) (for batch file you need to double the `%`):

```
wmic process where "Caption like 'AB%exe'" get Caption,ProcessId,Commandline /format:value
```